# from .cv2 import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I used to play with opencv but now I am not able to use it. When I enter :

```
import cv 2
```

I get

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have  32 bit Windows 7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: How did you install `opencv` ?

Comment: i installed it by pip

Comment: pip install opencv-python

Comment: Do you have the c++ 2015 redistributables installed? As explained in the FAQ of the module [web page](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

Comment: yes i have installed c++ 2015 redistributables

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue that really looked like this one.
I installed OpenCV on an  conda envrionement and someone had installed numpy unsing pip on the base environment.

Please check that:

- all your installed package come from compatible sources
- You don't have the same package installed twice

The only way that I could fix the issue was starting from a fresh environment.

Hope it helps